# Creating a list of substrings of a specified length in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have written a function which should return all substrings of a specified length, n, of a string. It will be called from another function and x will always be initially 0 ( I have only written in C and a counter is all I could think of).

```
allSubs :: Int -> Int -> String -> [String]
allSubs x n s
    |n>x = (take n (drop x (tail s))) ++ (allSubs (x+1) n s)
    |otherwise =
```

I hope the above function makes sense, in this function if the input was

```
allSubs 0 2 "john"
```

It should create a list

```
["jo","oh","hn"]
```

But I'd like to call another function with that list, but I can't get my head around how I could do that? And I don't know what to put in the otherwise case?

Comment: Try `otherfunction (allSubs 0 2 "john")` perhaps? And what about making `allsubs` actually work?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might be able to make your function a bit simpler and neater if you just pass the string's tail instead of passing the whole string and a counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `x` at all. The idea is simply to take the initial `n` characters of the string, then call recursively `allSubs` for the tail (everything except the first character) of the string, until we reach the point where the length of the string is too short to take `n` characters:

```
allSubs :: Int -> String -> [String]
allSubs n s
    | length s >= n = take n s : allSubs n (tail s)
    | otherwise = []
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d083814027dfe858)

A visual example is this:

```
allSubs 3 "ABCDE"
"ABC" : allSubs 3 "BCDE"               -- take 3 "ABCDE" : allSubs 3 (tail "ABCDE")
"ABC" : "BCD" : allSubs 3 "CDE"        -- take 3 "BCDE" : allSubs 3 (tail "BCDE")
"ABC" : "BCD" : "CDE" : allSubs 3 "DE" -- "DE" is too short to go forward
"ABC" : "BCD" : "CDE" : []
["ABC", "BCD", "CDE"]
```

The above solution is indeed not optimal. And optimized solution would be along the lines of:

```
allSubs :: Int -> String -> [String]
allSubs n s = allSubs' (length s) n s
    where allSubs' :: Int -> Int -> String -> [String]
          allSubs' l n s
              | l >= n    = take n s : allSubs' (l - 1) n (tail s)
              | otherwise = []
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b65e00c957c274b1)

The above solution removes the O(n) cost of computing the length at every iteration.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad it was a simple solution.

Comment: Computing the length on each iteration is not very efficient. It makes sense to compute it once instead and pass the "counter" to another helper function.

Comment: @user2407038 I agree. I've posted an "optimized" solution.

Comment: Doesn't GHC memoize function calls in some circumstances?